# Return array of doubles from a registered delegate method of other class

Tags: c#, vtk

Supossing I have button, when is pressed then It registers methods from other previously created class, and I am interested on result from `OtherClassLeftReleasedCb` from other method, so:

```
private void MainClassBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            vtkInteractorObserver istyle = goPreviewer.ImageViewer.GetRenderWindow().GetInteractor().GetInteractorStyle();

            istyle.LeftButtonReleaseEvt += new vtkObject.vtkObjectEventHandler(OtherClass.OtherClassLeftReleasedCb);

        }
```

the method of other class works fine, however I want to return array like:

```
public void OtherClassLeftReleasedCb(vtkObject sender, vtkObjectEventArgs e)
        {
            //do stuff
            myresult = new double[4];
            myresult [0] = stuffcomputedbefore[0];
            myresult [1] = stuffcomputedbefore[0] - stuffcomputedbefore[0];
            myresult [2] = stuffcomputedbefore2[1];
            myresult [3] = stuffcomputedbefore2[1] - stuffcomputedbefore[1];
         }
```

If I change return type to double[] to OtherClassLeftReleasedCb, then I would get error because when doing

```
istyle.LeftButtonReleaseEvt += new vtkObject.vtkObjectEventHandler(OtherClass.OtherClassLeftReleasedCb);
```

I am not telling that it should get array od doubles.
I do not know how to get `myresult` from extern method, Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than having `OtherClassLeftReleasedCb` conform to the signature of the event that you have, write it using the signature that you want it to be:

```
public double[] OtherClassLeftReleasedCb()
{
    //do stuff
    myresult = new double[4];
    myresult [0] = stuffcomputedbefore[0];
    myresult [1] = stuffcomputedbefore[0] - stuffcomputedbefore[0];
    myresult [2] = stuffcomputedbefore2[1];
    myresult [3] = stuffcomputedbefore2[1] - stuffcomputedbefore[1];
    return myresult ;
 }
```

Then have your other class create another method (possibly an anonymous method, if you want) that calls this other method and then possibly does something with the result:

```
private void MainClassBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    vtkInteractorObserver istyle = goPreviewer.ImageViewer.GetRenderWindow()
        .GetInteractor().GetInteractorStyle();

    istyle.LeftButtonReleaseEvt += (s,args) =>
        DoSomethingWithArray(OtherClass.OtherClassLeftReleasedCb());
}
```

Comment: so first thing to do is: 
`private object DoSomethingWithArray(double[] p)
        {
            //use double array p
        }` however I would get this error on: 
`istyle.LeftButtonReleaseEvt += (s,args) =>
        DoSomethingWithArray(OtherClass.OtherClassLeftReleasedCb());`
            saying "Error 4 No overload for method 'OtherClass.OtherClassLeftReleasedCb' takes 0 arguments " ?, Those arguments were originally: `OtherClass.OtherClassLeftReleasedCb(vtkObject sender, vtkObjectEventArgs e)` What am I missing?

Comment: @cMinor I removed the arguments because I assumed they weren't being used.  If you really need them, by all means keep them in the definition and pass the values in when calling it.  If you don't need them, just remove them.

Comment: the question is How?, because previously I was doing: `istyle.LeftButtonReleaseEvt += new vtkObject.vtkObjectEventHandler(OtherClass.OtherClassLeftReleasedCb);`
 so What would be the needed conversion in `istyle.LeftButtonReleaseEvt += (s,args) =>
        DoSomethingWithArray(OtherClass.OtherClassLeftReleasedCb());` ? How to add parameters `vtkObject sender, vtkObjectEventArgs e` ?

Comment: @cMinor The parameters are `s` and `args`.  Simply pass them to the method, if the method needs them.